# How to enable concurrent requests for Azure web app service

Tags: python, azure, flask, web, azure-web-app-service

I have a simple flask app that can be summarized as the following:

```py
from flask import Flask
import time

@app.route('/')
def home():
    time.sleep(5)
    return "done"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True)
```

When I run the Flask app locally, it is able to process concurrent results: I can call the app `GET /` and the request is processed in parallel. (For example, if I call the route `GET /` 5 times, it takes 5 seconds to process.)

However, when I call the same Flask app on a deployed Azure web app service, the requests are sequentially queued one after the other. (For example, if I call the route `GET /` 5 times, it takes 25 seconds to compute.)

I tried the following:

- changing deployment plan from production to development
- increasing the number of compute instances from 1 to 3

And the Azure web app still cannot handle HTTP requests concurrently (in parallel).

How can I enable concurrent (parallel) HTTP requests for the Azure web service app?

Answer (score 2):

In azure app services, app is run using gunicorn which is a python web server gateway interface HTTP server. You can specify the number of parallel python processes (workers) by having a gunicorn.conf.py file inside the root of the project folder which you deploy to azure. You can set the number of workers like this.

`workers = 3`

Can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#container-characteristics).